LLDB debugging doesn't work with std::cin
I have written a code like this:
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int a,b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a+b;
}

After running the run command in GDB, I managed to complete the input. But with LLDB, I can't enter it anyway.
I tried google and did not find anything about it.
What should I do?

I can input on GDB

I can't input on LLDB. I ran the run command on the command line and a window popped up with the file name I compiled. I am unable to input anything in the new window, even though cin is waiting for my input at this time. When I randomly input something in the LLDB of the back window (even if they are not LLDB commands), I can input it normally in the front window. Why is this?

What version of lldb are you using? It works fine with lldb 18.1.8.

Repeating my comment from the staging ground: I see two different consoles on the last picture, it's not clear if you tried inputting into both. If both don't work, what happens when you try? You press keys and no symbols appear, or what?

@cigien 18.1.8, too. I have updated more detailed information at the end of the question

@HolyBlackCat I have updated more detailed information at the end of the question

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872306 looks related. Could you check if the solutions work for you?

Don't post pictures of texts. Post texts as texts in code blocks.

@3CxEZiVlQ Seeing two consoles being opened (the second picture) is valuable information, that would be lost if they just pasted the text.

@HolyBlackCat Nothing would lost. Since the (lldb) prompt is present, the program doesn't run.

@3CxEZiVlQ In fact, the program runs in the top window. What I am puzzled about is that I cannot input in this window, and my program actually includes cin.

I can reproduce. Very peculiar. Perhaps this should be reported as a bug.

I haven't used lldb on Windows.  On other platforms, the run alias is just process launch -X true -- so using run does not ask lldb to open a separate tty and try to use it.  Opening a tty is requested by adding the -tty option to process launch.  You might try just process launch instead of run, that shouldn't try to open a separate TTY and should behave as gdb does.  Definitely worth a bug if the -tty option isn't working for you.

@JimIngham I made further attempts. After starting LLDB, no matter what way I run it, I can't enter it. But after you enter any text in LLDB, using the run command gets the input properly. In other words, the first command executed after starting LLDB is abnormal.

I think this is definitely a bug.

Sharing a terminal is always hard, especially because lldb needs a fairly sophisticated terminal to support edit line, but then needs to switch to whatever mode the target program expects when lldb returns control to it.  This all works for me on macOS, but it sounds like it's not working correctly on Windows.  If you have time, it would be good to file a bug at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.

@JimIngham I tried it elsewhere and it worked fine. I suspect it's due to some computer settings. I was using Terminal but they were using cmd, and I also installed clink. I'm looking further to see what the cause is.
